# PKCE using backchannel to refresh token

Tags: node.js, angular, single-page-application, openid-connect, pkce

I have a project that uses node-oidc-provider and angular-oauth2-oidc.

However one thing is wierd, refresh token request uses `prompt=consent` (I know it is by spec) which returns 303 with location including code in the hash, **the token is refreshed but it looks like terrible UX if SPA appplication refreshes in middle of user interaction**, is this expected behaviour or is something in my configuration wrong?

Is there any way to get refresh token through backchannel like AJAX request (I would like to avoid iframes if possible)? I can't find any specs on how it should work.

Answer (score 4):

**OPTION 1**

The traditional SPA solution is to use an Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) redirect on a hidden iframe using `prompt=none`. This prevents refreshing the SPA since it runs in a mini app as in [this code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/index.ts). This is no longer reliable though, due to recent browser restrictions that drop the SSO cookie - eg in Safari.

**OPTION 2**

Another option is to use a refresh token grant message in an Ajax request. But this relies on storing a refresh token in browser local storage to get past page reload issues. And this is not considered secure and is not likely to fare well in PEN tests etc.

**OPTION 3**

The preferred option these days is a variation on option 2 where the refresh token is stored in a secure HTTP only encrypted cookie. It is possible to issue cookies via an API, if you want to avoid impacting the web architecture, though it is a little tricky. See this Curity [blog post](https://curity.io/blog/token-handler-the-single-page-applications-new-bff/) for more on this approach - and [this code sample](https://github.com/curityio/web-oauth-via-bff).